# Excel formula for calculating interest rate of earning

Tags: calculation, rate-of-return, spreadsheet

On January 1st I invest 1238. I do this every January 1st for 20 years. At the end of 20 years (So December 31st of the 20th year), I have 32880 in the account. What's my rate of interest?

By playing around with excel and creating 20 rows of changing values, I find that the interest rate is 3.5787%. I believe this to be the answer.

But I cannot find any set of values to plug into the `Rate()` function to get me this result. Seems Rate() always rants a negative value plugged in which doesn't make sense to me. And it reports 2.6 or 2.9% depending on interest being calculated at the beginning or the end of the period.

[Edit]: People have mentioned to use `RATE()`. Here's what I get:

`rate(20,-1238,0,32880,0)` = 2.885

`rate(20,-1238,0,32880,1)` = 2.629

Neither of those are my expected answer.

Edit2:
As I mentioned in the comments, I placed an interest value into B1. Then I put 1238 into A1. I made A2 = *((1 + B1) * A1) + 1238*. Then I repeated for A3-A20. I then played with B1 until the end result was as expected. I got 3.5787%. My problem was that this only accounted for 19 years of interest. I needed to create 21 rows, not 20. And the last row would not add the $1238 again. Doing this I am able to plug in 2.629 into B1 and get the result I expected.

Comment: You had it right with RATE -- pmt is negative if your putting money in -- use end of period.

Comment: I edited to show the Rate() results. It does not seem right.

Comment: If you build a table of deposits and interest for 20 periods (interest based on `RATE(20,-1238,0,32880,0)`) you end up with 32880

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the 2.63% is the rate. That's what:

```
=RATE(20,-1238,0,32880,1)
```

gives, as does:

```
=XIRR(R2C2:R22C2,R2C1:R22C1)
```

(with 1238 in R2C2:R21C2, -32880 in R22C2, 1/1/95 through 1/1/14 in R2C1:R21C1, and 12/31/14 in R22C2) and if you check that by "hand", that is in some column, in rows 2-21, put:

```
=POWER(1.0263,20-ROW()+2)*1238
```

then sum those, you get $32,884.11, which is just some rounding away from $32,880.

Why do you expect 3.5787% to be the answer?

Comment: So I stuck a percentage into cell B1. Then I stuck 1238 into A1. I then set A2 = (A1*B$1+A1+1238). So interest on what was there, plus what was there, plus a new payment. I extended this 20 rows. Then I played around with the interest in B1 until I got the expected ending value.

Comment: Ok, yes the last row just needs to be the final year of interest. Then your procedure is the same as my =POWER formula, and in fact gives the same final answer, $32,884.11. This is exactly why I calculate stuff like this two different ways, if you get the same answer, you're probably doing things correctly, if you get different answers, you can investigate which way is right.

Comment: FWIW, if you go in Excel to *DATA/What-if Analysis/Goal Seek* you can have Excel do the "playing around" with the interest rate to give you desires final total...